# Rewriting API url

Tags: nginx

How can I configure NGINX to redirect my API URL?

I want to have /api/v1/projects/24 be redirected to /api/v1/projects/index.php?id=24

I thought this location block would work but I just get 404

```
location = /api/v1/projects {
                rewrite          ^/(/.*)$ /?id=$1 redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location = /api/v1/projects` will not match `/api/v1/projects/24`, it only matches `/api/v1/projects`. See [the `location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation.

If you want to **externally** redirect `/api/v1/projects/24` to `/api/v1/projects/index.php?id=24` (as your question suggests) you could just use a `rewrite` statement in the `server` block.

```
rewrite ^(/api/v1/projects)/(\d+)$ $1/index.php?id=$2 redirect;
```

---

If you really mean to **internally** redirect the requested URL to a PHP handler, use:

```
rewrite ^(/api/v1/projects)/(\d+)$ $1/index.php?id=$2 last;
```

See [the `rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) documentation.